# How can I check if a value already exists in mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to store a `name` in the mySQL database. When I click the <kbd>submit</kbd> button, PHP should check if the `name` already exists in the database. If yes then do not submit and print an error message:

> Name already exists in database.

```
<?php 
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];

            $valid = true;

            if ($valid) {
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO people (name) values(?) ";
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array($name));

            }
        }
    ?>

    <form action="form.php" method="post">
          <input name="name" type="text"  value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>">
          <button type="submit" >Submit</button>                
    </form>
```

Comment: Use select query to check the particular value is available or not. If not available then do the insert query

Comment: when you select, use  `num_rows` to see if there is a row.  If there is greater than 0, then kick out an error, otherwise insert.

Comment: Declare the column as `UNIQUE` and catch the exception. No need for two queries.

Comment: thank you! @ mario, is it possible to print an error message with UNIQUE?

Answer (score 4):

Try following query to check if a value already exists in mySQL database?

```
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM people WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1");
$q->bindValue(':name', '$name');
$q->execute();

if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
    $check = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $check['name'];
    // Do Something If name Already Exist
} else {
    // Do Something If name Doesn't Exist
}
```

Comment: Nice one, @Shehary. Thanks on my own behalf!

Answer (score 0):

you could declare the column as `unique` and check if the query executes or not, for example:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = :name");
$query->bindValue(':name', '$name');
if ($query->execute()){
    //no duplicate
}
 else {
    //error, check the error code.
    echo "$stmt->errorCode()";
}
```

`$query-> execute` will retun true on success and false other wise, and the database will return an error when the input is a duplicate in a `unique` coulmn.
I think Making the duplication check in the database is safer.